# Type of boost::future<> from boost::async()

Tags: c++, boost, future, boost-thread

I am getting unexpected results from `boost::async()` (Boost 1.56, Windows: VS2010 and VS2012).

```
#include <boost/thread/future.hpp>
...
auto func = [](){ return 123; };
auto boostFut = boost::async(func);
// boostFut = 42; // intentional error to reveal deduced type in compilation error
```

For some reason `boostFut` is deduced as `boost::unique_future<void>` instead of `boost::unique_future<int>`.

What am I doing wrong?

**Note:** on VS2012, if I used `std::async(func)` instead of `boost::async(func)` it does work as expected and the future *type* is deduced as `int`.

Comment: Version of `boost` is useful.  Oh, and sometimes boost functions want a `result_type` typedef in the passed in function object.

Comment: As stated above: Boost 1.56. Can you elaborate on the `result_type` suggestion? The problem still remains even if I explicitly define: `boost::unique_future<int> boostFut = ...` in this case the `asyn()` assignment fails to compile.

Comment: Sorry missed that.  I know that some of the boost function adapters have required that the result type be explicit in the passed in object, or at the least will fall back on that if they cannot solve the problem.  Does your problem go away with a function pointer?  a `struct foo { typedef int result_type; int operator()() const { return 42; };`?  A `foo` without the `result_type`?

Comment: @AdiShavit try adding `#define BOOST_RESULT_OF_USE_DECLTYPE` before you include boost libraries

Comment: @PiotrS.: That did the trick! Where is that documented? Write it up as an answer and I'll mark it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`boost::async` needs to determine the resultant type of the argument functor's call. In order to do that, Boost uses its own `boost::result_of<T>` class template implementation. That is, `async` declaration looks as below:

```
template <class F>
boost::future<typename boost::result_of<typename boost::decay<F>::type()>::type>
async(F f);
```

Depending on the compiler's capabilities/boost's configuration, `boost::result_of<T>` trait may work in one of the two ways:

1. Use `decltype()` from the call expression.
2. Look for a nested `result_type` typedef within `F` or a nested `result<T>` class template within `F` (if a number of the functor's arguments is greater than zero, as overloads may exist).

If the latter approach (2) is used, neither of the aforementioned alternatives are applicable for lambda's type, therefore Boost ends up with default assumption *deducing* `void` as a return type.

To make sure your Boost implementation will use `decltype()` operator (that works for lambda's call expressions fine), you need to prepend a define prior to Boost headers inclusion:

```
#define BOOST_RESULT_OF_USE_DECLTYPE
```

or add this define to `boost/config/user.hpp` file.